# Inline edit in angular

Tags: angularjs

I did one simple inline edit in angular.Its working fine,But when I try to integrate with server side code am getting struggle.I dont know how to send edited field value while updating.

html:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="mydata" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                    <thead class="colorBlue">
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.No</th>
                            <th>Role Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="">
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in roleList | filter:searchText">
                            <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <span ng-hide="editMode">{{x.name}}</span>
                                <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="x.name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="edit fa fa-pencil-square-o" id="edit{{x.Id}}" ng-click="editMode = true;edit(x.Id)" ng-hide="editMode"></i>
                                <i class="update fa fa-floppy-o" id="update{{x.Id}}" ng-hide="true" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="editMode = false"></i>
                                <i class="editCancel fa fa-times" id="editCancel{{x.Id}}" ng-click="editMode = false" ng-hide="true" ng-show="editMode"></i>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

script:

```
<script>
    var app=angular
                .module("intranet_App", [])
                .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.values = {

                    };
                    $http.post("/Admin/getUserList")
                    .then(function (response) {                     
                        $scope.roleList = response.data;
                    });
                    $scope.edit=function(val){
                        $scope.editing = $scope.items.indexOf(val);
                    }
                    $scope.update = function (val) {
                        $http.post("/Admin/UserUpdate")
                        .then(function (response) {
                            alert("updated successfully");
                        })
                    }
                    //$scope.cancel = function (val) {

                    //}
                })
</script>
```

Am getting table data from this method `/Admin/getUserList`
while updating the rows I need to pass edited data to this method `/Admin/UserUpdate`

Please any help?

Comment: *`..while updating the rows I need to pass edited data..`* So do you want to make service call on every input change\keyboard press?, then you can go for `ng-change` but will be very poor design in terms of performance., rather create some button and call method on `ng-click` to use post api.